# CryptoJS how to generate a key every time?

Tags: javascript, cordova, encryption, cryptojs

Let assume that I have an Phonegap mobile app, and I want to store some user data(username/pass_hash) in local indexed db for providing login to app in offline.
I want to encrypt that data of course, and my app already use CryptoJS.
As I understood, first I need to generate encryption_key by password using PBKDF2, and then just encrypt CryptoJS.AES.
Example code:

```
function generateKey(p){
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
return CryptoJS.PBKDF2(p, salt, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000 });     
}

var pass = "test1"; 
var iv  = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
key512Bits1000Iterations = generateKey(pass);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key512Bits1000Iterations, { iv: iv });
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key512Bits1000Iterations, { iv: iv });

//decrypting with another key step
key512Bits1000Iterations2 = generateKey(pass);
var decrypted2 = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key512Bits1000Iterations2, { iv: iv });
console.log("decrypted " + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
console.log("decrypted2 " + decrypted2.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Dynamic salt and iv are used.
But when I second time generate key for decryption by same password I'm getting wrong result.(decrypted2 is empty)
**So I want to ask, what I should store between encryption sessions, 
salt and iv to ?(but as I understood it should be dynamic )**
Thanks!

Comment: If you're using salt for encryption, than you'd need to use the very same salt value to decrypt the message.

Comment: Thanks!
I also found a good article https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm may be useful someone.

Answer (score 1):

You are generating a new salt in `generateKey(...)`. This makes **PBKDF2** derived a new key.

```
function generateKey(p){
    var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
    return CryptoJS.PBKDF2(p, salt, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000 });     
}
```

You would need to store the **salt** and **iv** between sessions. These two values don't need to be secret.